# Browser Push Notifications with self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: angular, ssl, https, push-notification

I have recently implemented browser push-notifications in an Angular app that is commonly used without SSL. Therefore I set up the IIS server and the angular server to use https, but with a self-signed certificate. I thought the warning message at the start and the red warning in the address bar would be the only drawbacks, but I was told by testers that they can't activate push notifications on several browsers, even when using https.
It worked for me, so I don't know what the problem might be.
Does anyone know why this happens or how I can make browser notifications work without an SSL certificate?

Comment: *"... use https, but without certificate ..."* - you likely mean with a self-signed certificate instead of some publicly trusted certificate. *"It worked for me, ..."* - probably because you trusted the certificate or even imported it explicitly as trusted, while others did not.

Comment: yes we configured a self-signed certificate in IIS, but on my machine I only accepted the default browser warning.